# Changing the localisation.resx always changes the public to internal modifier

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, localization

When I change my localize.resx in our asp.net mvc application the public access modifier always gets changed to internal which causes build errors due to access level restrictions.

why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the resx file in Solution Explorer and select Properties. Change the Custom Tool to PublicResXFileCodeGenerator (just type it in). Now it will use public instead of internal.,